# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67, Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-5

I've finished my local Laravel development. Now I'm publishing it with DigitalOcean and Laravel Forge.
The problem is I have the error

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
    in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    ...
```

My session driver is database.

My tries :

```
- DROP database mydatabase;
- CREATE database mydatabase;
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan views:clear
- php artisan key:generate
- php artisan migrate --force
```

Then

```
-> Login/Register page TokenMismatchException line 67 :(
```

Have I missed something?

PS: My local version doesn't have that problem. CSRF tokens are correctly included in requests (local or prod versions).

Comment: share ur .env and ur form code pls

Comment: have you edited session.php? and  What session driver  you are using! and did you edit your app service provider?

Comment: Can you dump() all requests? Like dump(Request::all()) ?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Thank you very much!!! The problem was in `config/session.php` the domain was my local virtual domain, I changed it to an .env variable and problem solved! Please write it as an answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the right session domain in

```
 config/session.php
```

I'd recommend to set this from an `.env` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Set below in your form then try

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I've already added this. Please see the "PS" in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Set csrf_token() function in the form like below

```
    <form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   </form>
```

Comment: Same as krunal nerikar answer, I've already added this. Please see the "PS" in my question. Thank you